# How to use html code in fpdf to create a pdf?

Tags: php, html, fpdf

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('asset/logo.png',10,6,20);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
     $this->SetDrawColor(0,80,180);
    $this->SetFillColor(230,230,0);
    $this->SetTextColor(220,50,50);

    $this->Cell(100,15,'FREE PEACE ASSESSMENT',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$html='<p>HI</p>';
```

$pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($html));

```
$pdf->Output();
```

**This is my code. i just used $html to use writehtml But i got a error with
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDF::WriteHTML()*
 *Error: Call to undefined method PDF::WriteHTML()*  ....**

Comment: Use this $pdf->WriteHTML('<p>HI</p>');

Comment: i used this type of code but not response injust add  below content it work

Answer (score 1):

Fpdf by default is not provided write HTML function. You need to develop code.

```
<?php

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    protected $B = 0;
    protected $I = 0;
    protected $U = 0;
    protected $HREF = '';

    function WriteHTML($html)
    {
        // HTML parser
        $html = str_replace("\n",' ',$html);
        $a = preg_split('/<(.*)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        foreach($a as $i=>$e)
        {
            if($i%2==0)
            {
                // Text
                if($this->HREF)
                    $this->PutLink($this->HREF,$e);
                else
                    $this->Write(5,$e);
            }
            else
            {
                // Tag
                if($e[0]=='/')
                    $this->CloseTag(strtoupper(substr($e,1)));
                else
                {
                    // Extract attributes
                    $a2 = explode(' ',$e);
                    $tag = strtoupper(array_shift($a2));
                    $attr = array();
                    foreach($a2 as $v)
                    {
                        if(preg_match('/([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)/',$v,$a3))
                            $attr[strtoupper($a3[1])] = $a3[2];
                    }
                    $this->OpenTag($tag,$attr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function OpenTag($tag, $attr)
    {
        // Opening tag
        if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
            $this->SetStyle($tag,true);
        if($tag=='A')
            $this->HREF = $attr['HREF'];
        if($tag=='BR')
            $this->Ln(5);
    }

    function CloseTag($tag)
    {
        // Closing tag
        if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
            $this->SetStyle($tag,false);
        if($tag=='A')
            $this->HREF = '';
    }

    function SetStyle($tag, $enable)
    {
        // Modify style and select corresponding font
        $this->$tag += ($enable ? 1 : -1);
        $style = '';
        foreach(array('B', 'I', 'U') as $s)
        {
            if($this->$s>0)
                $style .= $s;
        }
        $this->SetFont('',$style);
    }

    function PutLink($URL, $txt)
    {
        // Put a hyperlink
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
        $this->SetStyle('U',true);
        $this->Write(5,$txt,$URL);
        $this->SetStyle('U',false);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
    }
}
$pdf = new PDF();
// First page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<br><p align="center">center a line</p>and add a horizontal rule:<br><hr>');
$pdf->Output();
```